# Excel Screen Updating to False Using ExcelDna

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

I am trying to set Excel Screen Updating to false using ExcelDna. I do not want to use COM. Using its XlCall is preferred. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `XlCall.xlcEcho` to enable/disable screen updating. E.g.:

```
// Disable screen updating
XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcEcho, false);

// Enable screen updating
XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcEcho, true);
```